# On extended reals Topology

Tags: general-topology

Consider $\mathbb{W}=\mathbb{R}\cup \{ \infty,-\infty\}$ as the extended reals, and we define:

- $\tau_1:=\{ [a,\infty):a\in \mathbb{W}\} \cup\{\mathbb{W}\} $
- $\tau_2:=\{ [a,\infty]:a\in \mathbb{W}\} \cup\{\mathbb{W,\emptyset }\} $

so... I'm not sure if are they are a Topology in $\mathbb{W}$. I was wondering to give a counterexample using the intervals (in $\tau_1$)

$[\frac{1}{n},\infty), n\in \mathbb{N}$ and realize that arbitrary union of those intervals does not stays in $\tau_1$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Don't forget the empty set in the topology

Comment: consider $a=\infty$ so ^[∞,∞) is the empty set

Comment: what about for $\tau_2$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner you are right, let me fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not topologies because
$\cup${ [x,$\infty$) : a < x < $\infty$ } = (a,$\infty$)
and
$\cup${ [x,$\infty$) : a < x <= $\infty$ } = (a,$\infty$]
are not open sets.

Comment: Why should they be?

Comment: @azif00, see edit.

Comment: I can't see why it became a left "open" intervals when we do the union?

Comment: @Blacks.   Clue:  if a < z, then a < (a + z)/2 < z.

Answer (score 1):

The standard topology on $\Bbb W=\Bbb R \cup \{-\infty,+\infty\}$ is to take

$$\{(a,b): a< b, a,b \in \Bbb R\} \cup \{(a,\rightarrow) \cup \{+\infty\}\mid a \in \Bbb R\} \cup \{(\leftarrow,a) \cup \{-\infty\}\mid a \in \Bbb R\}$$

as a base, making it order isomorphic and homeomorphic to $[0,1]$.

So a basic open set of $+\infty$ looks like $U_a:= \{x \in \Bbb W \mid x = +\infty \text{ or } x > a\}$ for some real $a$, and similarly for $-\infty$.

What you wrote down is not even a topology.